# Can't get Windows VHD file to boot

Tags: windows-7, vhd

I had a setup where I has 2 windows options on startup. Basically originally I had 1 hard drive with Windows 7 Pro, then I added another hard drive where I setup Windows 10 Pro. Somehow automatically a windows 10 generation boot menu was added so I could choose, but seems like for some reason it was added on the hard drive with Windows 7 Pro because I had it as priority for boot.

Anyway my guess is that after Windows 10 got an update this broke somehow and I couldn't boot anymore to the Windows 7 Pro hard drive. It would give some command like bar "_" then move to startup of Windows 10 Pro hard drive. If I pointed to Windows 7 Pro hard drive now it wouldn't boot either on manually selecting boot device.

I can access the files on it but I need to access SQL database for work and I cannot simply copy it and the program. I decided to try and convert the hard drive to VHD, and tried running it but that wouldn't work. Then I read somewhere about changing it to Generation 2 option when creating VM and now I get the following message:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwjSq.png)

Pressing F8 doesn't work.

I'm not sure that putting in a Windows 10 Pro image ISO and booting to it to fix startup will work because it's Windows 7 Pro. And I don't have original image for Windows 7 Pro and one I have doesn't work, says wrong version. Please advice on how to fix.

PS: As I posted this, I wanted to try and mount Windows 10 ISO image and boot to it just to try, however I don't see that option, I am not sure but guessing that the blue menu is just "BIOS" of the hyper-v? And not the actual image of VHD? As I should be able to mount another ISO to boot to but I can't. So not sure what's going on, maybe it's not bootable by Gen2 either.

Comment: From a WinPE/WinRE command prompt: `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD` _(UEFI: remove `&& BootRec /FixBoot`)_

Answer (score 0):

Try and install the Windows 7 drive inside another computer or use an adapter ( (connector type) to USB, but replace (connector type) to your drive's connector type, e.g. SATA or IDE), plug your Windows 7 drive into your computer, and boot to it through BIOS/UEFI.

If both solutions didn't work, but Windows 10 is still bootable, check the EFI partition by booting into it and mounting your EFI partition from your Windows 7 drive into an unused drive letter. Open CMD or Powershell as administrator and use the following command:
`mountvol Z: /S`
Replace Z: with an unused drive letter if it is already taken. Open Task Manager and kill "explorer.exe". Then, from CMD, type `explorer.exe` to restart it with admin privileges, open Explorer, and open the EFI partition. Reply to this answer with the contents of the folder "Microsoft".

Comment: Hi, so seems like somehow the hard drive has Windows 7 Pro installed but a Windows 10 boot manager on top of it. Tried booting from Windows 10 installation media and repairing startup, that doesn't work. If I try Windows 7 installation media it tells me I have different version installed, I probably don't have the disk that I installed with initially it was some OEM or Refurbishers version or something like that.

Comment: Tried mounting but it just hangs. Does not mount. Don't I need to input the disk number somehow to mount it?

Comment: @1Advanced this isn't a threaded forum. If you need to add more info to a question edit the question. If you need to reply to an answer, use the comments. DO NOT edit an answer someone else has posted to add commentary or replies.